# Number sequence: 1, 2, 9, 48, 120, 162

Tags: number-sequence

First time entering a puzzle so I have no idea if what I've made is too easy. But it's not on OEIS at least.

**Find the next term!**

1, 2, 9, 48, 120, 162, __

Comment: Hmm. Is it purely mathematical or not?

Comment: No non-mathematical shenanigans occur in the above sequence. @DonThousand

Comment: Actually, I guess it depends what you mean by purely mathematical. I'll probably just drop hints over time if it doesn't get answered.

Comment: I mean, can I predict the next term if all I know is math. Honestly, the term that's throwing me off is 120, since it has a divisor of 5, unlike all the other terms.

Comment: Then yes, it is purely mathematical. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strongly inspired by [Mahdi Mahmoodian's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94159/64484) answer:

> $a_n = n \times s$ where $s$ is the sum of digits in all previous numbers in the sequence
>
>
>   $a_1 = 1 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1$
>
>
>   $a_2 = 2 = 2 \times 1 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1 + 2 = 3$
>
>
>   $a_3 = 9 = 3 \times 3 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1 + 2 + 9 = 12$
>
>
>   $a_4 = 48 = 4 \times 12 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1 + 2 + 9 + 4 + 8 = 24$
>
>
>   $a_5 = 120 = 5 \times 24 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1 + 2 + 9 + 4 + 8 + 1 + 2 + 0 = 27$
>
>
>   $a_6 = 162 = 6 \times 27 \rightarrow$ sum of digits $= 1 + 2 + 9 + 4 + 8 + 1 + 2 + 0 + 1 + 6 + 2 = 36$
>
>
>   The answer is:
>
>   $a_7 = 252 = 7 \times 36$

Comment: Teamwork! I like it!

Comment: Awesome job! You got it.

Comment: good job. i didn't think about digits :))

Answer (score 5):

I got an idea but it's not complete yet. I will update it as soon as I find something else:

> The $i$th number has $i$ as the divisor.
>  $f(1) = 1 * 1 = 1$
> $f(2) = 2 * 1 = 2$
> $f(3) = 3 * 3 = 9$
> $f(4) = 4* 12 = 48$
> $f(5) = 5*24 = 120$
> $f(6) = 6 * 27 = 162$

Also, I find something that applies to the first 4 number:

> The second divisor of $i$th number is $\sum_{n=1}^{i-1}f(n)$.
>  Example: $f(4) = 4 * \sum_{n=1}^{3}f(n) =4 * (1 + 2 + 9) = 48$

But after $48$ it doesn't work.

So after all I know one thing about the answer:

> It's divisible by 7.

Comment: Good job for the first to get so close to the mark. Upvote from me. Just missing that last bit of the equation which Michal has finished.